# can we use original card details for paypal sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

just want to know that I have provided original card details while using paypal sandbox while testing. Will the sandbox charge the card which I used.

Answer (score 0):

Original card details wont work on the sandbox environment. That's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It will accept the transaction, as the card number (I assume) adheres to Luhn / MOD10. But it won't charge it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using original card details? Are you playing dude? No Sandbox is always for testing. By the way you can also check your card balance after payment through sand box :-)